# How can I scale by time a canvas scaler > scaler factor float value from 0.01 to 1?

Tags: unity, c#

[image: Scale Factor]

The minimum is 0.01f the maximum I want it to be is 1
I want that when I start a Coroutine to be able to decide the time it will take to change the value to 1 and also the direction if from 0.01 to 1 or from 1 to 0.01

I tried this :

```
if (buttonType == "LoadGame")
        {
            StartCoroutine(DisplaySavedGamesWindow(5f, true));
        }
```

And

```
IEnumerator DisplaySavedGamesWindow(float time, bool direction)
    {
        float scaler = GameObject.Find("Save Slots").GetComponent<CanvasScaler>().scaleFactor;

        float currentTime = 0;
        while (currentTime < time)
        {
            scaler = currentTime / time;
            currentTime += Time.deltaTime;

            yield return null;
        }
    }
```

I used a break point on the line :

```
scaler = currentTime / time;
```

I see that scaler is changing up to 1 or to 0.9 ot sure why it's not getting to 1
And also it's not changing the value to 0.9 or to 1 in the editor in the scale factor it's still 0.01

Also how to use the bool flag ? true should be from 0.01 to 1 and false from 1 to 0.01

Ok I managed to make it working to be changed up from 0.01 to 1 :

```
IEnumerator DisplaySavedGamesWindow(float time, bool direction)
    {
        float currentTime = 0;
        while (currentTime < time)
        {
            var scaler = currentTime / time;
            GameObject.Find("Save Slots").GetComponent<CanvasScaler>().scaleFactor = scaler;
            currentTime += Time.deltaTime;

            yield return null;
        }
    }
```

The problem now is that when it's changing the value from the script the result is gray.

This is how it looks like when I'm changing it to 1 in the editor :
You can see the blue scroll view on the left :

[image: When changing the value from 0.01 to 1 in the editor manual]

but when it's changing the value from the script the result is gray scroll view and not blue like before :

[image: The scroll view is gray now]

Comment: It looks like you answered your original question and then added a new question to the post. Now the post is very long and a little hard to follow. It would be easier for us to help you if you trimmed down the post, perhaps removing your original question and focusing down on your new question.

Comment: @Kevin I will edit my question. Thanks.